# iphone SDK: How to set the initial value of a UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone

I have a picker view that has a list of numbers to pick from. I want to be able to initialize the control at a particular row. For example, if the user specifies 10 as their default, then the control should be automatically positioned at that row when the control is first initialized.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You call `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` and pass it the index of the row you want selected.

This code causes a `UIPickerView` to spin through its numbers 0 to 60 before coming to rest on 0.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [thePicker selectRow:60 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [thePicker reloadComponent:0];
    [thePicker selectRow:60 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    [thePicker reloadComponent:1];
    [thePicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [thePicker reloadComponent:0];
    [thePicker selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    [thePicker reloadComponent:1];
}
```

In your case, to display row ten you would call something like:

```
[thePicker selectRow:10 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: It's not working as expected. I put this code in viewDidLoad for the controller.Not sure why?

        [tipPicker selectRow:5 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Comment: Just all to update, this will work only in viewDidAppear and not in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad

Comment: @FahimParkar So much thanks for your update. It does only work in viewDidAppear. Could you please explain why it is like this?

Comment: @Calios : try to print `NSLog("thePicker===%@", thePicker)` in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` and you will get reason. This happen because pickerview take time to load we don't find in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, instead of choosing the row, is to make the pickerview find the value that you want. The way is creating a loop to find it in the array and selecting it:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
    int i = 0;
    for(NSString* number in arrayName)
    {
        if ([stringValue isEqualToString:number]){
            [pickerViewName selectRow:i inComponent:0 animated:YES ];
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UITextField` with `UIPickerView`

```
[self.text_field setInputView:self.picker];
```

then use this:

```
self.text_field.text = [_myarray objectAtIndex:10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working for me , just one line of code .

**In Objective-C**

```
   [self.picker selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

**In Swift**

```
  picker.selectRow(2, inComponent:0, animated:true)
```

Hope this will help some one .